# Regression without intercept when evaluating correlation

Tags: regression, correlation, intercept

By default, a linear regression model minimizes the least squares function for inputs $X$ and outputs $Y$ by fitting the slope and intercept. If I'm only interested in the Pearson correlation coefficient between the predicted and true outputs, can the intercept safely be removed from the equation or can it potentially lead to improved correlation results?

Comment: If you are interested in the Pearson correlation coefficient, then you should estimate a Pearson correlation coefficient, not a linear model.

Comment: Hi and this is just a heads up: I'm not saying that you were doing this but DO NOT USE THE $R^2$ of the regression output without including the intercept. That's a big mistake because, without inclusion of intercept, the sums of squares decomposition no longer holds which causes $R^2$ to be meaningless.

Comment: Which equation are you proposing to remove the intercept from?  The regression of $Y$ on $X$?  In some cases, doing that may reverse the sign of the correlation between $\hat Y$ and $Y$

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the correlation between $x$ and $y$, then just calculate the correlation. You do not need to calculate a regression model to do that.

**If** you still want to get the correlation from the R-squared of the regression, you **must** include the intercept, else the R-squared will be the wrong one.